# Optimal number of clusters using K-Prototypes method in R

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am trying to cluster some big data by using the k-prototypes method. I am unable to use K-Means as I have both categorical and numeric data. 
I have been using the package "clustMixType" and have been able to create clusters if I define what k value I want.
I want to find the optimal k value though and can't find anything on this online already.

Comment: This is more of a methodology question. You should probably ask this on the data science stack exchange. There are multiple measures of the "quality" of a cluster partition. A set of them are available in the `clue` package.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for this site. That fact that you are using R seems to be irrelevant to your question. You should probably ask at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] if you need help deciding how to analyze your data.

Comment: A simple way to deal with this to optimize error + ck, where c is a reasonable constant.

Comment: Use an appropriate _internal clustering criterion_ to help you select the best k. That is, do clustering with different k (say 2 through 20) and compare the values of of the criterion on a plot. Pay attention to peaks, elbows on such a plot. I recommend either Ratkowsky–Lance or BIC (or AIC) clustering criterions because they allow for mix of quantitative and categorical data. You may find more on our site CrossValidated about `clustering criterions` aka `clustering validation indices`.

Comment: Thank you all for your response! I ended up worked out manually all the in-cluster errors and summing them and plotting a graph using the Elbow rule.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no generic optimal k.

It depends a lot on your dataset and your goal.
A lower K would yield more fuzzy prototypes but would generalize better. There are always trade-offs

One way to pick K is to plot the data, and look at it. Even then you might want to try other values to see if they work better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code as below to plot the elbow curve. The input to the code below is the .

```
data <- <input the data here>
# Elbow Method for finding the optimal number of clusters
set.seed(123)
# Compute and plot wss for k = 2 to k = 15.
k.max <- 15
data <- na.omit(data) # to remove the rows with NA's
wss <- sapply(1:k.max, 
              function(k){kproto(data, k)$tot.withinss})
wss
plot(1:k.max, wss,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")
```